# System.Threading.Task lifecycle

Tags: .net, task, lifecycle

I am trying to use System.Threading.Tasks.Task to do some work asynchronously. I guess my question fits into the lifecycle of Tasks.

I have created a class and include task in one function

```
class A 
{
public bool func(string msg)
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => store(message));
    return true;
}

public void store(string message)
{
    //open database connection, store message in database
}
```

}

I will use instantiate class A in my application and call A.func(msg). My question is after the instance of A has been disposed, will the task continue, i.e. store message in my Database?

Comment: I suspect you'd get a ObjectDisposedException or other exception on the running threads if you tried to forcefully dispose of the object. But even if you don't, you shouldn't be doing that, instead you should wait on the thread to terminate it's job before deleting object A.

Comment: @o_weisman : Thanks for pointing this out. To be clear, you're saying the task is aborted immediately after the object A is disposed and no message is stored into the database?  Is there anyway to get around this? I am using A object in the Page_load() of my ASP.NET aspx page. Need to repond to browser request without blocking to persist the data into Database.

Comment: I was saying I suspect the writing thread might throw an exception if you try to dispose it forcefully. Why must you do that? Can't the thread that created the A object and its thread just go back to listen to browser requests?

Comment: @o_weisman: Well, I guess I don't have the choice as you suggested right now given that I am using IIS to host my webpage. For each request based on my understanding of ASP.NET page lifecycle, IIS is responsible for creating and disposing a System.Web.UI.Page object in which my object A is used. Hence, I have no control of whatever is using creating A object.